# C# - Retrieve full path of file on network drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have an intranet web application that sits on an internal server running IIS 8.5.

My company have a network drive containing hundreds of folders where people store excel files and the web server has full access to this drive.

My application needs to allow the user to select a file from this network drive, which will then populate a text box with the full file path (relative to the root) which can then be saved to an SQL database.

I have tried using a `fileupload` control but that only gives the filename and I need the full path.

Apologies for not being able to show you any code but I dont know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the *user* have access to the network drive? If so, the browser's fileUpload implementation should allow them to browse to it. Otherwise, you'll have to have your web application present the files to them for them to select from.

Comment: They do have access to the drive but different users may have it mapped differently.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent javascript from knowing local files full path, many modern browsers have a security feature.
It can be done in old versions of IE browsers.